# Background-color browser condition

Tags: javascript, css, browser, cross-browser

Is there a way to choose `background-color` with a browser condition?

I want to do something like this:

**browser.css**

```
-o-background-color: red;
-moz-background-color: green;
-webkit-background-color: blue;
```

If the condition could be in *CSS* it will be better. If it's not possible, it can be in Javascript also.
But first, is this condition possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Read this very carefully, I'm only gonna type it once: "Not possible with CSS."

Comment: Ok man, Thanks :) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the browser used by your visitors using the window object:
e.g.

```
window.navigator.vendor
```

or

```
window.navigator.userAgent
```

Then you can modify or add a new stylesheet to the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But Is possible to use only `CSS`?

Comment: I don't think so. I know you can use conditional comments in html (more info here: https://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), but that's only for IE, not for opera / firefox / safari. 
@charAt's link is good, as it gives you the code you can copy and paste for the most part. Also, you might want to check out this wiki: https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way if you want to read up on all the different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this: [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

You can then add a simple conditional statements and use the DOM to change the background color.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But Is possible to use only `CSS`?